# How to create ads in iPhone using Intel xdk?

Tags: android, ios, iphone, angularjs, intel-xdk

This code not working on iPhone, but it will work on android phone. Why?

```
 function MyCtrl($scope){
        $scope.title = "ADMOB XDK";
        $scope.abrir = function(valor){
            var admobid = {};
    if( /(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) { 
        admobid = { // for Android
            banner: 'ca-app-pub-5323315994691685/5395031531',
            interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-5323315994691685/5395031531'
        };
    } else if(/(ipod|iphone|ipad)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
        admobid = { // for iOS
            banner: 'ca-app-pub-5323315994691685/3239667139',
            interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-5323315994691685/3239667139'
        };
    } else {
        admobid = { // for Windows Phone
            banner: 'ca-app-pub-5323315994691685/5395031531',
            interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-5323315994691685/5395031531'
        };
    }
    if(( /(ipad|iphone|ipod|android|windows phone)/i.test(navigator.userAgent) )) {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', initApp, false);
    } else {
        initApp();
    }
    function initApp() {
        if (! AdMob ) { alert( 'admob plugin not ready' ); return; }
        if(valor == 1){
            AdMob.createBanner( {
            adId: admobid.banner, 
            isTesting: true,
            overlap: false, 
            offsetTopBar: false, 
            position: AdMob.AD_POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER,
            bgColor: 'black'
        } );
        }else{
            AdMob.prepareInterstitial({
            adId: admobid.interstitial,
            autoShow: true
        });
        }
    }    
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Make use of basic formatting options.

Comment: Maybe this tutorial can help you: https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-xdk